# Problem when using npx create-react-app, only creates package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Each time I use npx create-react-app I get:

changed 1458 packages in 7m
Missing dependencies in package.json

The react apps not get created What is causing this issue?

the folder with my new react app only gets the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true
}
```

???